# Alternative syntax for self-invoking function?

Tags: javascript, function

While writing a javascript course for some coworkers, I accidently discovered an alternative syntax for self-invoking function. Does anyone know about it, is there some specifics to it ? I wasn't able to find documentation about it.

CODE :
classic syntax

```
    (function(){
      console.log("I'm self-invoked!");
    })();
```

alternate syntax

```
    (function(){
      console.log("Me too!");
    }());
```

Thanks for the hints !

Comment: It works exactly the same way; the parentheses are only necessary to prevent it from being parsed as an statement (a unary operator would also work).  What don't you understand?

Comment: @SLaks you don't understand... The parentheses makes it an eager execution, not parsing. Parsing is done during compilation time, not execution time.

Comment: @PauliSudarshanTerho: No; parentheses never affect execution beyond shaping the parse tree.  The parentheses are necessary to prevent a syntax error from parsing it as a statement.

Comment: That was better explained

Comment: What I mean about eager execution is that this set `x` instantly to the value instead of function to give it later; `let x = (function(){return 123})()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two are identical in meaning.

In both, the `(` at the start symbols the start [of an expression](http://es5.github.io/#x11.2). This indicates the start of [a function expression](http://es5.github.io/#x11.2.5) which we intend to invoke. Finally we invoke it. The difference is subtle and should not matter at all, let's explore it:

```
(function(){
  console.log("I'm self-invoked!");
})();
```

Here, `(` is to tell the compiler it's the start of an expression, the compiler evaluates the expression (a function expression in this case) and then invokes it (outside the expression).

```
(function(){
  console.log("Me too!");
}());
```

Here - the invokation pattern ( `()` ) is *part* of that very expression.

Comment: Thanks, it's clear now.

Comment: @jonBreizh You're welcome, I've made this answer community wiki so other users could edit it and add more info (and because the question is pretty basic too). If you'd like to add to it - you're welcome to.